# django south migration not updating database

Tags: python, django, django-models, sql-update, django-south

Okay so I am creating a django app and I have installed the south app in the 'INSTALLED_APPS' section in my settings.py. I have been using the

```
python manage.py schemamigration myapp --auto
python manage.py migrate testapp
```

commands and they have been working perfectly until recently, made a change to my model.

```
class Users(models.Model):
    days = (('1', '1'), ('2', '2'),)
    day = models.CharField(verbose_name='', max_length=1, default='Day')
```

now, as you can see, I made two errors here. First is that I set the default to 'Day' when it isn't even an option in the variable 'days'. I also said that the max_length=1 and the default is 3 digits long. After running the schemamigration and migrate commands, it said gave an error saying

```
DatabaseError: value too long for type character varying(2)
```

and then when I did

```
python manage.py runserver
```

it did give the choices except 'Day' was not the default, the default was '1'.
I then added 'Day' as the choices and I changed max_length=3 except now when I do

```
python manage.py schemamigration myapp --auto
python manage.py migrate myapp
```

it still is giving the DatabaseError. I tried it again and when I did the schemamigration command, it said that there were no changes made and then when I tried doing the migrate command, it still gives the database error.

I was thinking to run a SQL command form the command line to update the max length of 'days' to 3 but when I viewed the database in PostgreSQL (the database linked to my app) it says that there is no 'days' column created.

Anyone have an idea on how to fix this?

Comment: can you show thesource code including the choices part you are using after making the changes? That might help. And you could inspect your database (e.g. using sqliteman or your preferred tool) and check what the table layout actually is.

Answer (score 0):

In database check the south_migration_history table.

There may be already an entry for particular app and for migration you are running.

so if name of your south migration starts with 0003 make sure before migrating that it is not in south_migration_history for that particular app.

If there is already an entry for your migration in south_migration_history delete that and run the migration command again.

Try it.